# Business Object reports running in a period of time

Tags: sql, business-objects

I'd like to know if I can query (via the Query Builder) the reports run by all users in a predetermined time interval.

With

```
SELECT SI_NAME, SI_UPDATE_TS, SI_CREATION_TIME 
  FROM CI_INFOOBJECTS 
 WHERE SI_KIND IN 'Webi, FullClient' 
   AND SI_UPDATE_TS > '2013.07.01'
```

we get all the reports updated from 2013.07.01, where `SI_CREATION_TIME` is the report creation time; instead I need to extract  **the reports run by all the users in the last year for example**

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a query through the Query Builder, you're retrieving data from the CMS repository, which contains no historical data.

If you want to know which documents were run by which users in a given timeframe, you need to use the **audit database**.

Whether you can retrieve the information from said audit database depends on a number of things:

- In contrast to the CMS repository, the audit database is not a prerequisite for a BOBJ environment. Thus, you might not have an audit database set up in your environment.
- The amount of actions recorded into the audit database is configurable. You should check to see if your environment is configured correctly to audit the actions that you're interested in.
- In BI4, the audit database can be configured with a retention period. By default, this retention is set ridiculously high, but it might have been modified in your environment, leaving you with insufficient data to run your analysis.
- In BI4, an audit universe is no longer supplied by default. However, you can download and import an audit universe supplied by SAP. There are two versions: the [original audit universe](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-6175) and an [improved version](http://scn.sap.com/community/bi-platform/blog/2015/07/15/unlock-the-auditing-database-with-a-new-universe-and-web-intelligence-documents-for-bi41).